# Contact Sensor doesn't work in Gazebo 9

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm trying to create contact sensor with Gazebo 9 + ROS Melodic, here is my code:

test.urdf.xacro

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="test" xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">

   <link name="chassis">
    <inertial>
      <mass value="100" />
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <inertia ixx="16.66666" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="41.66665" iyz="0.0" izz="41.66665" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <box size="2 1 1" />
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision name="chassis_collision">
      <geometry>
        <box size="2 1 1" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>

  <link name="bumper"><box size="0.1 0.1 0.1" />
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.1 0.1 0.1" />
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision name="bumper_collision">
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.1 0.1 0.1" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>

  <joint name="chassis_bumper_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="chassis" />
    <child link="bumper" />
    <origin xyz="1 0.5 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
    <axis xyz="0 0 1" />
  </joint>

  <gazebo reference="bumper">
    <sensor name="bumper_sensor" type="contact">
      <always_on>true</always_on>
      <update_rate>30</update_rate>
      <contact>
        <collision>sensor_collision</collision>
      </contact>
      <plugin name="bumper_plugin" filename="libgazebo_ros_bumper.so">
        <bumperTopicName>bumper_sensor</bumperTopicName>
        <frameName>bumper</frameName>
      </plugin>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>

</robot>
```

simple.world

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sdf version="1.4">
<world name="default">
    <include>
        <uri>model://sun</uri>
    </include>
    <gravity>0 0 -9.8</gravity>
    <include>
        <uri>model://ground_plane</uri>
    </include>
</world>
</sdf>
```

launch file

```
<launch>

  <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch&quot;&gt;
&lt;arg name=&quot;world_name&quot; value=&quot;$(find simulation_app)/worlds/simple.world"/>
    <arg name="paused" value="false"/>
    <arg name="use_sim_time" value="true"/>
    <arg name="gui" value="true"/>
    <arg name="headless" value="false"/>
    <arg name="debug" value="false"/>
    <arg name="verbose" value="true"/>
  </include>

  <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro --inorder $(find simulation_app)/urdf/test.urdf.xacro" />
  <node pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" name="spawn_urdf" args="-urdf -param robot_description -model test"/>

</launch>
```

I expect to get something when bumper touches ground plane since chassis has inertial but instead I'm getting empty states in bumper_sensor topic when it happens:

*header:

    seq: 6693

    stamp: 

        secs: 257

        nsecs: 555000000

    frame_id: "bumper"

        states: []*

Does anybody know if I'm missing something?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/23933/contact-sensor-doesn%27t-work-in-gazebo-9/) by [Tony](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/17296/tony/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-10-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Ok, so the catch was that I'm using xacro instead of urdf... This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RcrgC9o9A6A) explains everything in details, in short - when you use xacro, it will be converted to sdf where collision names will be completely different (in my case `bumper_collision` turned into `chassis_fixed_joint_lump__bumper_collision_collision_1`) so to make it work:

Convert xacro to urdf (yes, "xacro xacro ", it's not a typo):

```
rosrun xacro xacro test.urdf.xacro > test.urdf
```

Convert urds to sdf:

```
gz sdf -p test.urdf > test.sdf
```

Get the right collision name from sdf file and use it in xacro for sensor collision

```
<collision>chassis_fixed_joint_lump__bumper_collision_collision_1</collision>
```

Hopefully it will help somebody to not run into the same issue I did

---

Originally posted by [Tony](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/17296/tony/) with karma: 1 on 2019-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0